# In PHP, How to call a function interpolated in string?

Tags: php

Let's say my string is:

```
$str = "abcdefg foo() hijklmopqrst";
```

How do I let PHP call the function `foo()` and insert the returning string to the rest of that string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$str="abcdefg foo() hijklmopqrst";
function foo() {return "bar";}

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("~([a-z]+)\(\)~", 
     function ($m){
          return $m[1]();
     }, $str);
```

output:

```
$replaced == 'abcdefg bar hijklmopqrst';
```

This will allow any lower-case letters as function name. If you need any other symbols, add them to the pattern, i.e. `[a-zA-Z_]`.

Be **VERY** careful which functions you allow to be called. You should at least check if $m[1] contains a whitelisted function to not allow remote code injection attacks.

```
$allowedFunctions = array("foo", "bar" /*, ...*/);

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("~([a-z]+)\(\)~", 
     function ($m) use ($allowedFunctions) {
          if (!in_array($m[1], $allowedFunctions))
              return $m[0]; // Don't replace and maybe add some errors.

          return $m[1]();
     }, $str);
```

Testrun on `"abcdefg foo() bat() hijklmopqrst"` outputs `"abcdefg bar bat() hijklmopqrst"`.

Optimisation for whitelisting approach  (building pattern dynamically from allowed function names, i.e. `(foo|bar)`.

```
$allowedFunctions = array("foo", "bar");

$replaced = preg_replace_callback("~(".implode("|",$allowedFunctions).")\(\)~", 
     function ($m) {
          return $m[1]();
     }, $str);
```

Comment: What if the function has parameters?

Answer (score 33):

If you're calling a method of some class, you can use normal variable expansion.  For example:

```
<?php
class thingie {

  public function sayHello() {
    return "hello";
  }

}

$t = new thingie();
echo "thingie says: {$t->sayHello()}";
```

This will output:

> thingie says: hello

Note that the braces around the call *are* required.

Comment: But it seems calling a global function this way, won't work

Comment: By wrapping the global functions you want to support in an object of methods, you can control the footprint of exposure to bugs and security leaks.  I think you'd be hard-pressed to find an easier way to /safely/ offer such power.  Your wrapper methods can even perform additional validation/restriction if needed.

Answer (score 25):

Just use this:

```
$str = "abcdefg".foo()."hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

It will call function during string creation.

Answer (score 21):

```
function foo()
{
    return 'Hi';
}
$my_foo = 'foo';
echo "{$my_foo()}";
```

Comment: This is a great "trick." You can even pass parameters or other variables to it, ie. `echo "{$my_foo('bar')}"` or `echo "{$my_foo($bar)}"` - especially useful when building SQL queries with many escaped values.

Answer (score 11):

```
$foo = foo();
$str = "abcdefg {$foo} hijklmopqrst";
```

Answer (score 7):

### Short answer

No. There is no native construct to do exactly that.

A simple concatenation may be better. Maybe uglier but more efficient for the PHP parser.

### Long answer

Well. Yes.

If you really need to get arbitrary expressions being evaluated from a double-quoted string, you can implement this workaround, speculating on a feature called *variable-functions*:

```
<?php
/**
 * The hack
 *
 * @param $v mixed Value
 * return mixed Value (untouched)
 */
$GLOBALS['_'] = function ( $v ) {
    return $v;
};

// Happy hacking
echo "Today is {$_( date( 'Y-m-d' ) )} and the max function returns {$_( max( 1, 2, 3 ) )}...{$_( str_repeat( ' arrh', 3 ) )}!";
```

Result:

```
Today is 2018-02-07 and the max function returns 3... arrh arrh arrh!
```

The example is not limited to `date()`, `max()` and `str_repeat()`: you can surely define your own functions like `foo()` and just call them, as long as they return a valid string.

In short this example creates a simple variable. It has a very short name: just an underscore. So, the variable is really called `$_`. This variable, to be honest, it's a function and, to be honest, it just returns what you express in the first argument. This is syntax sugar for you, since functions are not easily expanded as-is inside a string. Instead, variables are expanded easily. That's it.

I wonder if PHP will ever introduce a native feature to do that (note: I've written this note in 2018).

### Limitations

Note that, even in this way, the functions are expanded when you define the string. I really cannot guess your needs, but if you need to expand the function later, and not during string definition, you probably need to adopt something more advanced, like a parser. There are many, especially suitable for text templates. But that is outside the scope of this answer I guess.

Feel free to comment / suggest other approaches to expand functions *inside* a string or just improve your question to share more context about your need.

References:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: long answer: definitely NO (but you can use some obfuscated hack).  

Please note, this solution won't work if the interpolated string is inside a function. You would have to use $GLOBALS['\_'] or global $\_; what is a huge pain.

Answer (score 5):

Its still not possible, There are hacks available but not what I would recommend  rather suggest to stick with old school dot operator i.e. `$str="abcdefg ". foo() ." hijklmopqrst";`

As per the [Complex (curly) syntax documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

> Note:
>   Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string is defined. Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
<? 
function foo($b)
{
    return "Hi $b";
}
$bar = 'bario';


$my_foo = 'foo';
echo "<br>1 {$my_foo($bar)}"; 

$myfoo = foo; // my 'version'
echo "<br>2 {$myfoo($bar)}"; 

// the following is nogo; php error! $myfoo can not be called as function because it got the return value if foo() which is a string.
// means https://stackoverflow.com/users/517676/savinger answer above is wrong; this program doesn't print "<br>end":
 
$myfoo = foo();
echo "<br>3 {$myfoo($bar)}"; 

echo "<br>end";
?>
```

The output is:

```
1 Hi bario
2 Hi bario
```

Comment: `$myfoo = foo;` is not "your" version but a PHP error. The only working solution is the first one and it's already provided. This answer has zero value.

Comment: great comment YCS, but note, 1st, i wrote // my 'version' not // 'my' version. which should make clear that it was meant ironically--though it even works. 2nd, that it works due to a php error is not in my responsability. 3rd, both ways are a bad hack and not a solution. 4th, the value i added and which was the reason for my post was to point out that a previous 'solution' (savinger) remained uncriticized --to the contrary, he got 10 upvotes!--, but to which i couldn't *comment* due to having not enough reputations, so i chose to *answer* instead.

Comment: "it even works" - where I live, [it doesn't](https://3v4l.org/gIIEX). "was the reason for my post was to point out that a previous 'solution' (savinger) remained uncriticized" - I fail to see *any* mention of it in your answer. And personally, I don't see any drawbacks in the savinger's solution which is clear and straightforward (and has nothing to do with any of your hacks which actually resemble that from v.babak's answer).

Comment: aha, i see, it depends on the php version. i still use php 5.5. mea culpa. it's the version that runs on my server. the output I gave for $myfoo = foo; echo "<br>2 {$myfoo($bar)}"; is authentic. I ran the example. whereas (repeat) savinger's 'solution' produces and error with php 5.5. I mentioned in my example // https://stackoverflow.com/users/517676/savinger

Comment: using $myfoo = foo; echo "<br>2 {$myfoo($bar)}"; on 3v4l.org; on my server i doesn't show the notice below: Output for 5.5.38 | released 2016-07-21 | took 23 ms, 16.83 MiB
Notice: Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo' in /in/gIIEX on line 9
<br>2 Hi bario

Comment: savinger's 10 times upvoted answer above which i criticized and which i mention in my example is $foo = foo(); with php 5.5 and still with most recent php version produces: Output for 8.3.1 | released 2023-12-21 | took 19 ms, 23.41 MiB
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function foo(), 0 passed in /in/kLHEE on line 9 and exactly 1 expected in /in/kLHEE:3
Stack trace:
#0 /in/kLHEE(9): foo()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /in/kLHEE on line 3

Process exited with code 255.