# can't write through file_put_contents

Tags: php

i have php script where i write result to file through file_put_content but it not writing for one variable...when i give static value it is working. my code is.

```
<?php
$uuid = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $dmid));
$establish = "\n\n START -- ".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')." serial-no:".$uuid.",if:".$res_value['if']."\n";
file_put_contents('filter.log', $establish);
?>
```

when I `echo $uuid` it displays `03000200-0400-0500-0006-000700080009` but it write on `filter.log` file like `START -- 2017-09-26 06:06:24 serial-no:,if:em1` i tried trim function not any help...i don't how to done this please help me.

Comment: You have not given us enough information to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

When are you echoing $uuid?
The syntax looks good to me but you can try another syntax.  The difference below is that the variables are in-line and not concatenated.  You can do this with php as long as you use double-quotes.  Also, the curly brackets are not necessary but if you use them they guarantee the variables name. see: [When to wrap curly braces around a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598187/when-to-wrap-curly-braces-around-a-variable) :

```
<?php
$uuid = trim(str_replace(' ', '', $dmid));
$now = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo $uuid;
$establish = "\n\n START -- {$now} serial-no: {$uuid},if:{$res_value['if']}\n";
file_put_contents('filter.log', $establish);
?>
```

Comment: `{date('Y-m-d h:i:s')}` won't work like you expect it to.