# Using LIKE Wildcard is causing random characters

Tags: php, postgresql, wildcard, sql-like

I have a php script with a query like so:

```
$b = $a[0];  // 2115
$c = $a[1];  // 2197
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT a.document_id 
        FROM archive_locations a 
        INNER JOIN archive_locations b 
           ON (a.document_id = b.document_id) 
           AND 
           (
              a.street_address LIKE '%$b%' 
              OR a.location_name LIKE '%$b%' 
           )
           AND 
           (
              b.street_address LIKE '%$c%' 
              OR b.location_name LIKE '%$c%' 
           )
           ORDER BY a.document_id;";
```

But when I echo this query, I get this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.document_id 
FROM archive_locations a 
INNER JOIN archive_locations b 
   ON (a.document_id = b.document_id) 
   AND 
   (
      a.street_address LIKE '%!15%' 
      OR a.location_name LIKE '%!15%' 
   )
   AND 
   (
      b.street_address LIKE '!97%' 
      OR b.location_name LIKE '!97%' 
   )
   ORDER BY a.document_id;
```

It seems the character `%` is causing the issue.  I tried escaping it, but there must be some special escape or pattern needed that I am unaware of.  I could use some help.  Thanks!

Comment: Use parameters.,  Don't munge query strings.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - example please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way with curly braces e.g `{` and `}` before and after the variable name.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT a.document_id 
        FROM archive_locations a 
        INNER JOIN archive_locations b 
           ON (a.document_id = b.document_id) 
           AND 
           (
              a.street_address LIKE '%{$b}%' 
              OR a.location_name LIKE '%{$b}%' 
           )
           AND 
           (
              b.street_address LIKE '%{$c}%' 
              OR b.location_name LIKE '%{$c}%' 
           )
           ORDER BY a.document_id;";
```

**When to use curly braces:**

> When you are defining a variable inside a string, PHP might mix up the
>   variable with other characters if using simple syntax to define a
>   variable and this will produce an error

See more: [When to wrap curly braces around a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598187/when-to-wrap-curly-braces-around-a-variable?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I had already tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work. Same results.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you then you can try like this also `LIKE '%" . $a. "%'"` . Let me know is that worked or not?

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: I know you are using postgresql but without php?

Comment: No, I'm using php 7.  `pg_escape_string` doesn't work either