# How to add link to echo variable in php

Tags: php, html

How I can add a link to the slogan here?

```
<li class="sadguy"><?php echo esc_attr($top_bar_slogan); ?></li>
```

I have read other questions but I really didn't understand, can someone help me please?

I saw other answers that says I can use something like this:

```
<?php echo “<a href='http://www.example.com’>Click here</a>” ; ?>
```

But in my code it's variable not text "esc_attr($top_bar_slogan)"
Should I use it like this or it's wrong?

```
<li class="sadguy"><?php echo “<a href='http://www.example.com’> esc_attr($top_bar_slogan)</a>; ?></li>
```

Comment: Use string concatenation

Comment: I'm beginner and I want to learn, can you please explain it more?

Comment: `"<a href='http://www.example.com’>" . esc_attr($top_bar_slogan) . "</a>";` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002675/227299 also

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it doesn't work, it breaks my page <li class="sadguy"><?php echo "<a href='http://www.example.com’>" . esc_attr($top_bar_slogan) . "</a>"; ?></li>

Comment: Please edit the question to say what you have tried, and show the broken output.

Comment: You can also just do `$slogan = esc_attr($top_bar_slogan);  echo "<a href='example.com’>$slogan</a>";`

Comment: Or even better: `<li class="sadguy"><a href='http://www.example.com’> <?php echo esc_attr($top_bar_slogan)?></a></li>` You should not be printing longs chunks of HTML with php, only the dynamic parts